# How to fix size error of Java Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, components, jpanel

I'm practicing about Swing Layout.
I seek JFrame's actual size is not match to size Dimension

```java
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GridRanFruit {
    public GridRanFruit() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel primary = new JPanel();
        primary.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 600));
        primary.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        JPanel panels[][] = new JPanel[4][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
                primary.add(panel);
                panels[i][j] = panel;
            }
        }

        int ranSeed = (int) (Math.random() * 16);
        panels[ranSeed/4][ranSeed%4].setBackground(Color.green);

        frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

You can find small error from below pictures. how can solve that?
I'm using `setPerferredSize` method.
it mean `JFrame` size is not matched with `JPanel` though same size

[error height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBSJ4.png)

[error width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVk4C.png)

[nomal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnGEP.png)

Comment: Set the preferred size of the JFrame's contentPane, not the JFrame itself.

Comment: Avoid `null` layouts, these are just going to give you issues.  Remember, the windows decorations are included inside the bounds of the window, so your available space will be the windows bounds minus the window decorations insets.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line where you are setting the size with

```
frame.setSize(600,600);
```

setPreferredSize(), like one of the commenters said, is for the content pane (the space inside the frame where things can be placed) rather than the frame itself (the borders of the window).